# Passing data with putExtra()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a question about passing data in Android Studio.

I want to pass data between 2 activities. In the second activity, I want to get URI of the image and load it into an ImageView.

Image From Main Activity, first step
[image]

In this picture, we see that the extras had been added, and the value "mImageUri" is set.

Image From Filter Activity, the second one
[image]

Then when I am into the second activity, I want to read this extra data and when I do it the value of 's' equals 'null'.

Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong?
Greetings.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the next line then check the debugger for the value of `s`

Comment: can you try calling getIntent().getStringExtra("ImageUri"); after super call in onCreate().

Comment: Value of 's' equals 'null'. It's even visible in the second picture.

Comment: did you tried what i suggested what i am thinking what before super may getIntent will may not work. so try calling it after super call on oncreate

Comment: Yes, I've already did it and nothing has changed. Value 's' still equals 'null'.

Comment: I thought this may be the problem. can you post something more about it because it looks fine otherwise?.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the full code/project?

Comment: Ok, everything works fine when, all I needed was adding '.toString()' in this line 

i.putExtra("ImageUri", mImageUri.toString());

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: @Stegenda was `mImageUri` not a `String` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your second Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String s = extras.getString("ImageUri"); 
}
```